# Overlap <div>s in CSS

Tags: css

So, I've seen tons of questions about this, but I would like a personal example.  I'm rather new to programming, so I may be a little stupid...

Anyway, I have two `<div>`s, one with id `bg` and the other with class `player`.

This is what it looks like:

[image: What it looks like]

The red box is the player, and the large image is the bg.

I need the player to start in the center of the bg.

The bg is 640px X 640px.

This is the code I have so far in my CSS file:

```css
#bg {
    width: 640px;
    height: 640px;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}

.player {
    position:relative;
    background-color:#FF0000;
    width: 32px;
    height: 32px;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;    
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing your stylesheet to:

```css
#bg {
    width: 640px;
    height: 640px;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    position: relative;
}

.player {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #FF0000;
    width: 32px;
    height: 32px;
    top: 320px;
    left: 320px;    
    z-index: 1;
}
```

And your HTML should look like this:

```
<div id="bg">
    <!-- your bd code here -->
    <div class="player"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: @minitech sorry because you edit is lost. Can you please do it again?

Answer (score 0):

`position: relative` is relative to where the object would be placed normally. In your example, it would normally come below the first div, so that's where it will stay. (In other words `position: relative` used with a positioning of `0` won't move the objet anywhere.)

You could add `top: -320px; left: 320px`. That would position it it the space of the first div. But maxksbd19's answer is probably the better solution for your ultimate goal.

Answer (score 0):

I try and avoid absolute positioning as it does not adapt to the container size and a change to the container requires you to go through your css and change all the absolute values.

I would do the following

CSS:

```
#bg {
            overflow: auto; /* stops the .player from from moving #bg down */
            width: 640px;
            height: 640px;
            background-color: blue;
            text-align: center; /* center child div in IE */
        }

        .player {
            background-color: White;
            width: 32px;
            height: 32px;
            margin: 0 auto; /* center div in parent for non IE browsers */
            margin-top: 304px; /* 50% from top minus div size */
        }
```

HTML:

```
<div id="bg">
    <div class="player"></div>
</div>
```

Now you only have to keep track of the top margin of the child container.